# Parsing/Extracting the SOAP Body using Tibco Designer

Tags: tibco

I am receiving HTTP requests on a Tibco service using **HTTP Receiver** element, and I would like a way to extract or parse the Soap Body from the Request, without resorting to using the **Soap Event Source element**. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

you can receive SOAP request across SOAP palette or service palette

Comment: Does not fulfill my needs, still requires use of Soap Pallete

Answer (score 0):

You can use serviceagent for soap requests and map your request to related process , serviceagent will check your configuration and send your soap body to process directly